# Angular 2 not detecting changes in service variable from component

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to update my component to display the correct value of a service variable when it changes. I currently have this:

**Component1 HTML**

```
{{icons | json}}
```

**Component1**

```
icons: {
  icon1: boolean,
  icon2: boolean,
}

constructor(private _service: Service1) {
  this.icons = this._service.navIcons;
}
```

**Component2**

```
constructor(private _service: Service1) {
  this._service.signIn();
}
```

**Service1**

```
navIcons: {
  icon1: false,
  icon2: false
}

navIconsChange: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

constructor() { 
  this.navIconsChange.subscribe((value) => { this.navIcons = value; console.log(value) });
}

resetIcons() {
  this.navIconsChange.next(
    this.navIcons = {
       icon1: false,
       icon2: false
    });
}

signIn() {
  this.navIconsChange.next(
    this.navIcons = {
       icon1: true,
       icon2: true
    });
}
```

The idea is that when the signIn() method is called from Component2, the navIcons should update and those updates should display on Component1. The console.log I have in the subscribe logs that this change took place, however, the icons in Component1 HTML never update. I would assume these should automatically update since the icons are getting updated in Component1's constructor from Service1. How can I get these variables to update when Component2 calls the signIn() method?

This is all based off of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43161506/4927000

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify much of your code as you are doing many things wrong way.

Component 1

```
icons: {
  icon1: boolean,
  icon2: boolean,
}

constructor(private _service: Service1) {
    this._service.navIconsChange.subscribe((value) => {
     this.navIcons = value; 
     console.log(value) 
    });
}
```

Service 1

```
navIcons: {
  icon1: false,
  icon2: false
}

navIconsChange: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

resetIcons() {
  this.navIconsChange.next({
       icon1: false,
       icon2: false
    });
}

signIn() {
  this.navIconsChange.next({
       icon1: true,
       icon2: true
    });
}
```

Component 2 and Component1 HTML will remain same.

This way your `comopnent 1` will know when ever value gets changed.

Also if you want to cache the result in service for other component you can manually assign it to variable after `.next` or use `BehaviourSubject` like:

Service 1

```
navIcons = {
  icon1: false,
  icon2: false
}

navIconsChange: Subject<any> = new BehaviourSubject<any>(navIcons);
```

Add comments if you need further help.

Comment: This seems to be on the right track, however the subscription seems to take a while to execute. Also, I'm getting the following error:
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: true'. Current value: 'ngIf: false'.

I was getting this error previous when calling the service directly from the HTML so I wanted to change it. Any ideas as to why this would be happening?

Comment: I got the error to go away by adding a setTimeout() function to the subscription as seen in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45444242/4927000. Everything is working fast and how I would expect, but I can't help but think this is a poor way to execute. Thoughts?

Comment: Nevermind, I realized I was changing these values in ngOnInit(), not the constructor so it sounds like the changes were made before Change Detection took place. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Josh I hope everything is working fine for u. But don't use `setTimeout` in your code may be you can post the complete error or code to help under stand the issue. @acdcjunior i am so amazed to see that you such great learning attitude and take feedback positively. I would try to copy that too. :D

Comment: Yes, everything is working great without using setTimeout. I had a feeling that wasn't a great option. :) Thanks again for your help, I was able to fix the ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError by moving my code into the constructor instead of the ngOnInit.