# How to update header component when data changes in service?

Tags: javascript, angular

Reference: [How can I detect service variable change when updated from another component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43159090/how-can-i-detect-service-variable-change-when-updated-from-another-component)

Current Behavior: Users login and the menu items does not update when variable values changes in the header component. It only updates when the page is refreshed.

Expected Behavior: Hide menu some of the menu items when user logs in - immediately.

Header component contains menu and subscribed to authentication service:

```
isAuthenticated: boolean = false;

this.items = [
  {
    title: 'Home',
    link: '/',
    home: true,
  },
  {
    title: 'Dashboard',
    link: '/dashboard',
    hidden: !this.isAuthenticated,
  },
]
ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.isAuthenticated().subscribe(res => this.isAuthenticated = res);
}
```

Comment: At a guess, `isAuthenticated()` only returns a stream of a single value, and doesn't get updated by the `authService` as needed.

Comment: @jonrsharpe  `isAuthenticated()` is updated when users login or logout. And both login and logout has `ChangeDetectorRef` for detecting changes.

Comment: Then another problem might be that `!this.isAuthenticated` is probably only evaluated once. But give a proper [mcve].

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, `!this.isAuthenticated` is updated only once.

Comment: Why did you expect otherwise? If it's outside a method, when *would* it get updated? It's not a magic reference to the `isAuthenticated` property, it's just the value `true`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe How to trigger the method which each update? The subscription is also called once.

Comment: You need to recalculate `this.items`. Maybe make it an accessor.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I can recalculate that/ or update the `isAuthenticated` but the problem is catching the change in the serivce. I am subscribed to the service but I want to trigger a method each time change in service.

Answer (score -1):

You should use array filter
for example

```
this.authService.isAuthenticated().subscribe(res=>{
    this.isAuthenticated = res
    res.filter(elem=>{
        this.isAuthenticated = res
    }
} );
```

Comment: `res` is a boolean, TypeScript won't like this at all.